# Do you create a Pinia store for each feature in your application?

Tags: vuejs3, pinia

Just starting to work with Vue 3 (compositional api) with Pinia for local storage where you can have many individual stores.

Many of the examples I see have a Pinia store setup for each feature i.e. users store, customers store, products store, etc. Each store has an actions to fetch, update and delete from their respective service.

Is this normal practice or is it overkill?  I understand the need to locally store current_user or setup preferences but one for each feature seems excessive.

Also is there any downside of having many stores and maintaining them?

Comment: It's normal to use each store for each module. It is the way we split code and group them by logical concern. It helps us maintain the code easier.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense but would you also store, for instance, the array of products in Local Storage too or are you just essentially accessing your services through the store?  My concern is that if I have 50 modules in an application that it will lead to large amounts of data being stored locally

Comment: The key point here is that pinia is not related to Local Storage. You can use pinia without storing anything in Local Storage. But you can decide to store some of the pinia states on Local Storage to reuse them for the next time the user visits your site

Comment: Ok, perfect.  Thanks for clearing that up.